No se ha dado ningún argumento que corresponda al parámetro formal requerido
Estoy realizando un proyecto en el cual quiero agregar un login, sin embargo, al agregar el private void msjError, me dice ese mensaje de arriba con un "msj" de "Form1.msjError(string)" y la verdad no sé cómo arreglarlo, acá dejo el código:
namespace proj_sem
 {
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    static string cadenaConexion = "Data Source=xx\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial 
    Catalog=tienda;" + " Trusted_Connection=True; integrated security=true";
    SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion);
    SqlCommand comando;
    SqlDataAdapter datos;
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        msjError();

    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            conexion.Open();

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error al realizar la conexión");
        }
    }

    private void btn_Registro_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string nombre = txtnombre.Text;
        string apaterno = txtap.Text;
        string amaterno = txtam.Text;
        string fechanac = dtp.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        string usuario = txtuserreg.Text;
        string contra = txtpassreg.Text;
        string repetirc = txtpassrepetir.Text;
        if (nombre != "" && apaterno != "" && fechanac != "" && usuario != "" && contra != "")
        {
            if (contra == repetirc)
            {
                string insertar_usuario = "insert into ussers (nombre, apaterno, amaterno, fnacimiento, usuario, contraseña)" +
                "values('" + nombre + "','" + apaterno + "','" + amaterno + "','" + fechanac + "','" + usuario + "','" + contra + "');";
                SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(insertar_usuario, conexion);
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Los datos han sido registrados correctamente", "¡ÉXITO!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                nombre = "";
                apaterno = "";
                amaterno = "";
                fechanac = "";
                usuario = "";
                contra = "";
                repetirc = "";
                panel_Form.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Las contraseñas no son iguales", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Faltan campos por rellenar", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

    }

    private void btn_in_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string usuario = txtuss.Text;
        string pass = txtpass.Text;
        string validar_existencia_usuario = "select * from ussers where usuario='" + usuario + "' and contraseña='" + pass + "'";
        comando = new SqlCommand(validar_existencia_usuario, conexion);
        datos = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
        datos.Fill(tbl);
        if (tbl.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Form4 llamar = new Form4();
            llamar.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            msjError("Usuario o contraseña incorrecto.");
            txtuss.Text = "";
            txtpass.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel_Form.Visible = false;
    }

    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        panel_Form.Visible = true;
    }


    private void msjError(string msj)
    {
        lblErrorMessage.Text = "    " + msj;
        lblErrorMessage.Visible = true;
    }

}
}

no sé qué se supone que debo agregar o quitar dentro de pero por más que muevo, sigo sin encontrar el problema. Indica que es en la linea 26 que aquí sería donde dice msjError(); en el public Form1(), es de las primeras veces que meto nuevos private voids y quizás algo me falló en el proceso.

Esto ya lo había probado en otro form con la misma redacción y con la respuesta dada, sin embargo sigue apareciendo, no clasifica como error de escritura al ya ser hecho, como fue mencionado, con esa misma estructura y en todo caso que lo fuera, sería más útil que lo demostrasen y evitar solo mostrar algún tipo de descontento, gracias.

La solución es la que te indico en mi respuesta

La función debe recibir un string como argumento
//    STRING DE ARGUMENTO ⇩
private void msjError(string msj)
{
   lblErrorMessage.Text = "    " + msj;
   lblErrorMessage.Visible = true;
}

Pero tú la estas invocando sin ingresar dicho argumento
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    msjError(); // <-- Falta ingresar el argumento en tu función
}

Yo no veo motivo para mostrar un error cuando se instancia el form, por lo que creo que simplemente debes borrar esa llamada a la función
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}


Yo creo que está pregunta tiene enormes probabilidades de terminar cerrada, ya que es un error de escritura del op

@Japv Hola estimado, evidentemente yo no estoy de acuerdo (no la habría respondido en ese caso).

como mencioné, es más útil comentar el por qué sería un error de escritura y en qué parte ya que tiene cierta urgencia y de alguna u otra forma busco solucionar este tipo de problemas rápidamente.

@Japv, difiero. Omitir un parámetro no es un error de escritura. Si comenzamos a ampliar el concepto, probablemente el 80% sería un error de escritura, pues se corrige cambiando como estaban escritas las cosas. Un error de escritura es cuando se escribe mal el nombre de un método, incluso mayúsculas/minúsculas en lenguajes case sensitive. Pero, omitir un parámetro, es otro tipo de error. Muchos programadores novatos podrían tener el mensaje de error al intentar compilar y obtener ayuda de esta respuesta al hacer una búsqueda por el mensaje de error.
